# Adding color to function output

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is using jquery. How to color the output when exceeding a certain number.

```js
$("#text").on("input", updateCount);

function updateCount() {
  count = $("#text").val().length;
  $("#count").text(count + "/20");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
    <div id="count">0/20</div>
```

So on 20/20 the first 20 need to be in red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the 20 should be red?

In any case, with a simple if-else you can check the value of count. When it is smaller than 20, use red, otherwise black.

With `.css(attr, value)` you can change the color of the element.

```js
$("#text").on("input", updateCount);

function updateCount() {
  count = $("#text").val().length;
  color = (count < 20) ? 'red' : 'black';
  $("#count").css('color',color).text(count + "/20");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<div id="count">0/20</div>
```

If it should be red after the 20, then change `<` to `>`

If you would like to use multiple steps and multiple colors, use a switch instead

```js
$("#text").on("input", updateCount);

function updateCount() {
  const count = $("#text").val().length;
  switch (true) {
    case (count < 5):
      color = 'red';
      break;
    case (count < 15):
      color = 'orange';
      break;
    case (count < 20):
      color = 'yellow';
      break;
    case (count == 20):
      color = 'blue';
      break;
    default:
      color = 'green';
      break;
  }
  $("#count").css('color', color).text(count + "/20");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<div id="count">0/20</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution where 20 shows red. Limited the textarea to 20 with HTML attribute as well.

```js
$("#text").on("input", updateCount);

function updateCount() {
  count = $("#text").val().length;
  $("#count").text(count + "/20");

  if (count >= 20) {
    $("#count").css('color', 'red');

  } else {
    $("#count").css('color', 'black');
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea maxlength="20" id="text"></textarea>
<div id="count">0/20</div>
```